# How to get the goal name or goal ID from Google Analytics in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, google-analytics, ssis, google-analytics-api

Is it possible to get the goal name or goal ID from the Google Analytics Source task (ZappySys) in SSIS?

I've been searching for it for a long time now and I just can't find it in the Dimensions or Metrics from the task.

I also tried to use the eventAction Dimension from the task, but the goalCompletionAll is not showing the same results from the website.

The Dimensions I've been using to compare are Source, eventAction and the Metric goalCompletionsAll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get the name of the goal, but you can get the specific goal value through its `id` (that you can see in the panel) using `ga:goalXXCompletions`.

Also, you **cannot** compare `event actions` and `goals` because they are different scopes, the first is at the `hit` level while the second is at the `session` level, for this reason you get different numbers.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!
I'll try again with the information you provided me.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Update: My problem was solved with your help, thank you again!